# how to customize an element-wise function on tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say, I have a tensor, it might contain positive and negative values:

```
[ 1, -1, 2, -2 ]
```

Now, I want to apply log(x) for positive values, and a constant -10 for negative values:

```
[ log(1), -10, log(2), -10 ]
```

In another word, I want to have a function like `numpy.vectorize`. Is this possible in tensorflow?

One possible way is to use a non-learnable variable, but I don't know if it can properly do back propagation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) enables you to map an arbitrary TensorFlow subcomputation across the elements of a vector (or the slices of a higher-dimensional tensor). For example:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, -1.0, 2.0, -2.0])

def f(elem):
  return tf.where(elem > 0, tf.log(elem), -10.0)

  # Alternatively, if the computation is more expensive than `tf.log()`, use
  # `tf.cond()` to ensure that only one branch is executed:
  # return tf.where(elem > 0, lambda: tf.log(elem), lambda: -10.0)

result = tf.map_fn(f, a)
```

Comment: thanks, I also found out that `tf.where` does the same job.

Comment: Yes: in fact, you should use `tf.where()` when the computation on either side of the condition is inexpensive, and use `tf.cond()` where the computation is expensive enough that you'd prefer to do it only when necessary. In this case, `tf.where()` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the `tf.where` does exactly this kind of job: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where